# Load a bootstrap modal through ajax - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to load a modal using ajax, here's my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("a").click(function() {
var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'modal_id' : Id,
        },

        url : "ajax.php",
        success: function(reponse) {
            if(reponse) {
                alert(reponse);
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
         });
});
});
```

And here's my `{a}` tag :

```
<a id="2" data-original-title="Preview" data-placement="top" class="data-tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_2"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span></a>
```

ajax.php :

```
echo "<div class='modal fade' id='modal_".$_POST['modal_id']."'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                    <h4 class='modal-title'>Preview</h4>
                </div>
                <div class='modal-body'>";

                echo "</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
```

How I can display the modal through ajax and why my code doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: does the javaScriot console print out an error?

Comment: i think you need a div which will hide onload and after a click add 
$('#alert').html(response);
$('#alert').show();

Comment: @RakeshSharma Still it only alert html tag but not the modal itself!

Comment: @Dinistro The console only load the ajax and doesn't show any errors!

Comment: @user3350731, when I copy your code to my websever, it works fine. do you see the loaded file in with the browser? (in chrome under Network)

Comment: Yes i do but it doesn't show like the modal in bootstrap it only alert ajax like : `<div class='modal fade' id='....`

Comment: @user3350731, do you mean, that the alert prints html code?
The alert will print everytime just blank html-code and will not formate it with css...

Comment: Exactly, is there a way instead of printing the code show the modal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to append the content of the modal box to the document body and actually opening the box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'modal_id' : Id,
            },
            url : "ajax.php",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response) {
                    $('body').append(response);
                    $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
                    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function (event) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<a id="2" data-original-title="Preview" data-placement="top" class="data-tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal_2"><span class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-new-window">gdfgdf</span></a>
<div id="alert"></div>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function() {
var Id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'modal_id' : Id,
        },
    url : "db_search.php",
        success: function(data) {
             $('#alert').html(data); $('#alert').show();
        }
         });
});
$('#2').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't execute your code since the tag `{a}` is generated with a `foreach` loop !!

Comment: you can modify it according your requirement